# Style autocomplete with Zurb Foundation

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, zurb-foundation

What is the best practice to use Foundation features instead of jQuery CSS for Autocomplete?

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/88kfb/

```
<div class="row">
 <form class="custom">
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Fieldset</legend>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns ui-widget">
   <label for="tags">Input Label</label>
    <input id="tags" type="text" placeholder="large-12.columns">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I just don't like to include another .css file which is overhead on the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to use `dropdown` from Foundation or something? It seems like `dropdown` is only for `topbar` and its css screwed up outside that particular use case.
2. What is some "standard" way to create the dropdown menu in Foundation? Please help with some example. Because I was thinking it's either bunch of `rows` or it could be a tweak from `dropdown`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try to add the 'f-dropdown' class via jquery to the :

```
 $('.ui-autocomplete').addClass('f-dropdown');
```

also set on the app.css o youystyle.css:

`.ui-helper-hidden-accessible{display:none}`

I hope it helps... http://jsfiddle.net/vgarcias/WdncE/

Answer (score 4):

Foundation is now trying to incorporate an auto complete by default, in its next version. You can find the entry in this

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3100