# jquery ui autocomplete conflicts with foundation install with nuget

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, zurb-foundation

I used nuget to install foundation and jquery ui (which installs jquery). I have a an MVC 5 website that I am working on.

Before I added foundation the jquery autocomplete control was working fine. However, after install the control still kinda works but the dropdown that you make your selection in disappears.

I ran across this solution [Style autocomplete with Zurb Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167538/style-autocomplete-with-zurb-foundation) and this is from the same guy I think ... http://ezra.keddell.co.nz/implementing-jquery-autocomplete-in-zurb-foundation-4/ . They were the only solutions I ran across in my searches. However I don't think it will work for me because from what I can tell when you install foundation via nuget it doesn't come with jquery. So the files he wants to modify with the following code isn't valid and I wouldn't know which files would be the correct ones. Nor do I understand why this makes sense.

```
<script>
document.write('<script src=' +
('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +
'.js><\/script>')
</script>
```

I guess I'm looking for a way to get jquery ui and foundation to work together for the purpose of the autocomplet control. Is it possible to tell Foundation to stop working for a while or to have it not affect the styles for the autocomplete control.

The exact code that I have is ...

Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

@Styles.Render("~/Content/foundation/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/site.css")

@RenderSection("head", required: false)
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<div id="mainWrap" class="row">
    <div class="Columns small-12 small-centered">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>


@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/foundation")
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
@*Use the Scripts section to define page specific scripts*@
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

index.cshtml

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Name").autocomplete({

            //  how does the request get a value?
            source: function GetRemoteData(request, response) {

                var name = $("#Name").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET", 
                    url: "/api/attendees/" + name,  
                    cache: false,
                    data: request,
                    dataType: "json", 
                    success: function (json) {
                        // call autocomplete callback method with
                        response($.map(json, function (name, val) {
                            return {
                                label: name,
                                value: val
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, e) {
                        alert("error - " + textStatus);
                        console.log("error", textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                }); // end $.ajax
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                alert("you have selected " + ui.item.label + "Id: " + ui.item.value);
                $("#Name").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            }

        }); // end autocomplete

        // supposedly to help foundation and jquery ui work together.
        $('.ui-autocomplete').addClass('f-dropdown');


    }); // end ready

</script>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home")) { 

@*<label>Your Name:</label> <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="@Html.Raw(Model.Firstname) @Html.Raw(Model.LastName)" /> <br />*@
<label>Your Name:</label>    <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="" /> <br />
@Html.LabelFor( x=> x.Attending ) @Html.CheckBoxFor( x=> x.Attending ) @*<label>Attending:</label>*@  @*<input type="checkbox" id="Attending" name="Attending" />*@ <br />
@Html.LabelFor( x => x.Windermere ) @Html.CheckBoxFor( x => x.Windermere ) @*<label>Staying at the Windermere Manor:</label>*@ @*<input type="radio" id="radioYes" /> <input type="radio" id="radioNo" /> <input type="radio" id="radioMaybe" />*@ <br />
@Html.TextAreaFor( x => x.Notes )<label>Notes:</label>  @*<textarea id="AttendanceNotes" name="AttendanceNotes"> </textarea>*@ <br />

<button id="Submit" name="Sumbit">Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: Why did someone vote this question down without even telling the poster why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really unfortunate but it was not a conflict between foundation and jquery ui ... if you look closely above you will notice that I did not include the jquery UI css stylesheet.